# Can a PWA work in an intranet?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, intranet

Lets assume that the intranet has SSL and the users are using Chrome in Android, will progressive web apps work?  Will it have offline caching?

Lets assume also that the push notification service will be sitting in their network, will it also have notifications?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Are you sure you really understand what progressive web apps are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Progressive Web app works where any website works, as long as it has a service worker, a manifest and SSL. When people are outside the company, they'd see the offline version.

Push notifications might work as well, but you need to be inside the company network to receive them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Sorskoot! More helpful than other answers

Comment: Push notifications will only work if the server sending the notification can connect to the Push notification providers (Google, Mozilla, etc) and the users browsers can also connect to the providers.